# Querying Huge Data in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I am retrieving all incoming user IP adress from my server, I have retrieved the adresses and wrote them to a file. I have also filtered the ip adresses from the file and retrieved them to a variable, ip. However, when I am unable to upload the ip adresses to the mysql database.

So far I have this but it does not work.

```
with open("netstat.txt", 'rb') as f:
    for row in f.readlines()[1:]:
        columns = row.split()
        if len(columns) > 2:
            ip = row.split()[1]
            user = row.split()[2]
            ip = ip.strip('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
            con = mdb.connect('server', 'user', 'pass', 'db');

            with con:
                cur = con.cursor()
                cur.executemany("INSERT INTO Juliet_Data(ip,user) VALUES,(%s,%s)" % ip,user)
```

I have the tables set to the following:

```
user = longtext
ip = blob
```

Error Given:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Documents and Settings\finance\Desktop\Server 
Monitoring\System Load Tracker\User Tracking\netstat.py", line 32, in 
<module>
     cur.execute("INSERT INTO Juliet_Data(ip) VALUES,(%s)" % ip)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 174, in 
execute
     self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, 
in defaulterrorhandler
     raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your 
SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
version for the right syntax to use near '()' at line 1")
```

Sample IP Adresses Look at Just the IP and the USer:

```
 0.0.0.0:22             newjulietleft:0        LISTENING
   TCP    0.0.0.0:135            newjulietleft:0        LISTENING
   TCP    0.0.0.0:445            newjulietleft:0        LISTENING
   TCP    0.0.0.0:1311           newjulietleft:0        LISTENING
   TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           newjulietleft:0        LISTENING
   TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           newjulietleft:0        LISTENING
   TCP    0.0.0.0:5800           newjulietleft:0        LISTENING
   TCP    0.0.0.0:5900           newjulietleft:0        LISTENING
   TCP    0.0.0.0:47001          newjulietleft:0        LISTENING
   TCP    0.0.0.0:49152          newjulietleft:0        LISTENING
   TCP    0.0.0.0:49153          newjulietleft:0        LISTENING
   TCP    0.0.0.0:49154          newjulietleft:0        LISTENING
   TCP    0.0.0.0:49158          newjulietleft:0        LISTENING
   TCP    0.0.0.0:49170          newjulietleft:0        LISTENING
   TCP    10.22.22.22:139        newjulietleft:0        LISTENING
   TCP    10.22.22.22:3389       gregk:17415            ESTABLISHED
   TCP    10.22.22.22:49156      superman:microsoft-ds  ESTABLISHED
   TCP    10.22.22.22:49160      juliet:microsoft-ds    ESTABLISHED
   TCP    10.22.22.22:49164      pong:microsoft-ds      ESTABLISHED
   TCP    10.22.22.22:49165      ftpserve:microsoft-ds  ESTABLISHED
   TCP    10.22.22.22:50376      dbmlog:3306            ESTABLISHED
   TCP    10.22.22.22:50377      hulk:microsoft-ds      ESTABLISHED
   TCP    10.22.22.22:50383      julietz:netbios-ssn    TIME_WAIT
   TCP    10.22.22.22:50384
```

Comment: What is "it does not work"?  What does it do?

Comment: `cur.executemany("INSERT INTO Juliet_Data(ip,user) VALUES (%s,%s)" % ip,user)` after VALUES was not needed comma

Comment: Now it says, Typerro: not enough arguemnts for format string.
    
    Values (%s,%s) % ip, us

Answer (score 3):

the `,` from after `VALUES,` is invalid

When you receive a syntax error you only need to look at where the error points to.  This error can be confusing because it doesn't give you the line in your script but instead inside mysql at the first statmeent you execute which is your insert statement.

For your second issue in your comment:

you should be using parameterization so something like:

`VALUES (?, ?), (ip, user)`

should work

Answer (score 0):

```
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO Julient_Data (ip,user) VALUES (%s,%s)", ((ip, user),)) 

cur.executemany("INSERT INTO Julient_Data (ip,user) VALUES (%s,%s)", ((ip, user),('192.168.1.1', 'test1')))
```